# How to allow excluding a module when importing my Python package?

Tags: python, package

I wrote a Python package `pack` that can perform a set of related tasks, `taskA`, `taskB`, ..., `taskZ`. Each of them has its own module file, e.g. `taskN.py`.

Now say in `taskN.py` I import a third party package `evilpack`. It Works On My Machine™, but a coworker of mine (a) can't install `evilpack`, but (b) does not even need that module `taskN`.

My goal is to structure my package so that we can choose at import time whether we want to load the module `taskN` or ignore it.

What's the most elegant way to solve this? I'm sensing it has something to do with the directories' `__init__.py` files.

Comment: using `__all__` in your code to exposure code / module to specific person will help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid a `from pack import *` statement, and instead ideally have a `import pack` for both me and my coworker. Would that still work in that case?

Comment: What is your criteria for exclusion? The code handling the imports must be able to know what to read from your coworker's system to exclude

Comment: @ycx I'm not sure what you mean by "criteria for exclusion", but I want to exclude exactly one pre-specified module within my package, and I am looking for a way to specify before/while importing whether or not to exclude that module - via some flag or option.

Comment: you can chose from requirment.txt file which package to  chose when building a package . dintinguish there which package are necessary for whole package(core component) and which are others then from there making the whole module like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to solve this problem:

Identify all of the modules that may have unfulfilled dependencies.

In the main module that does the importing, surround each such import with a `try...except` clause:

```
try:
    import packN
except ImportError as details:
    print ("Could not import packN because of this error:", details)
    print ("Functionality xxxx will not be available")
    packN = None
```

If your colleague's code doesn't call a function that relies on `packN` then all will be well.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it and it works exactly as advertised :) One more question if you don't mind: If I have like ten successive statements of the form of `from .subpack.taskN import TaskN`, with TaskM, TaskN, etc., is there a way to write a loop? I wouldn't know how to do a relative import by picking modules as a string, i.e. from a list of strings.

Comment: @AlexanderEngelhardt I've never tried importing in a loop but that is because I have never worked with 10 like-named imports that differ only in the digit in the name. You *could* call `__import__()` in a loop because that accepts the name of the imported module as a string. But if it's only 10 and not 300 I would do it the long way.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can only point you in the correct direction via [setupscript](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) because I do not have access to your data/package details.

To simply put, you will have to locate your `taskN.py`'s `setup.py` script, and specifically remove the module from inside the script.